# Como desabilitar um campo input do tipo slider em bootstrap-slider?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-3

Gostaria de saber como faço para desabilitar um campo `input` do `slider` em `bootstrap-slider`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para desabilitar um `slider` utilizando o `bootstrap-slider` depende da sua instância original do campo criado.

Por exemplo, se você criou seu `slider` `com jQuery` então sua instância ficou mais ou menos assim:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $("#slider1").slider();
});
```

Para manipular esse `slider` você precisa criar uma variável para que ele seja associado e possa facilitar a manipulação:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                var slidervar = $("#slider1").slider();
                slidervar.slider('disable');
    });
```

Já se a sua instância foi `sem jQuery`, então ela ficou mais ou menos assim:

```
Slider("slider1", {});
```

Para manipular esse `slider` você precisa criar uma variável para que ele seja associado e possa facilitar a manipulação:

```
var slidervar = Slider("slider1", {});
slidervar.disable;
```